# Google Chrome not connecting to websites

Tags: networking, 13.04, google-chrome

I upgraded from Ubuntu 12.10 to 13.04. On starting I found that google-chrome was not working. Starting google-chrome from the command line showed it was complaining about missing libudev.so.0. So I uninstalled Chrome and reinstalled it from the deb provided by Google. Now Chrome starts but does not connect to any websites outside the local network (we are behind a proxy). Firefox/Links etc work fine so the connection is okay. How could I go about fixing this?

Thanks,

ETA: On starting google chrome through the command line I get the following message:

```
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
GLib-GIO-Message: Using the 'memory' GSettings backend.  Your settings will not be saved or shared with other applications.
Created new window in existing browser session.
```

Comment: Please expand "ETA"?

Comment: Edited to add. I added the error message later.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work by giving the proxy server information on the command line. For some reason it is not picking the proxy server information from the system wide proxy settings.

```
google-chrome --proxy-server="proxy:port"
```